# AWS QLDB - GDPR support

Tags: amazon-qldb

I am planning for AWS QLDB for audit data.

1. Does QLDB support GDPR? Is there any performance impact to this?
2. There are some fields encrypted using custom encryption key before storing into QLDB. I might change the key down the line when the key gets compromised or for the key rotation policy. So, I may need to read all the old records, decrypt using old key and encrypt using new record and update again. Is this possible with QLDB?
3. How to do multi tenancy with QLDB? Like, I have multiple apps writing to audit and would like to have a virtual separation for each app in the same cluster.

Answer (score 1):

thank you for the question; it touches some of the concepts that is at the heart of QLDB.

> 1. Does QLDB support GDPR? Is there any performance impact to this?

The QLDB developer guide page on [data protection](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/qldb/latest/developerguide/data-protection.html) may help provide more information about the AWS shared responsibility model. It may also be helpful to read this [AWS blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/the-aws-shared-responsibility-model-and-gdpr/) about the shared responsibility model and GDPR.

We are currently working on a feature that will allow customers to remove the customer data payload from QLDB revisions. Many customers have asked for this feature in order to accommodate GDPR ”Right to forget“ requirements. Please do be aware that this is not a claim of ”compliance“ - as this is something you would need to evaluate independently. We do not anticipate this impacting any read/write performance. If you’re interested to know more about this, please reach out to AWS support and they’ll connect you with our team to tell you more about it.

> 2. There are some fields encrypted using custom encryption key before storing into QLDB. I might change the key down the line when the key gets compromised or for the key rotation policy. So, I may need to read all the old records, decrypt using old key and encrypt using new record and update again. Is this possible with QLDB?

Reading all the old records is possible in QLDB through a few different methods — [querying revision history](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/qldb/latest/developerguide/working.history.html), [exporting journal data](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/qldb/latest/developerguide/export-journal.html), or [streaming journal data](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/qldb/latest/developerguide/streams.html).

However, it is worth noting that QLDB does provide [encryption at rest](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/qldb/latest/developerguide/encryption-at-rest.html) via KMS. You can leverage KMS for key rotations or key expiry as well, and you’ll be able to access the old data with the new key via [KMS’s key hierarchy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/cryptographic-details/key-hierarchy.html). KMS will allow you to rotate keys without the need to reencrypt all your data.

> 3. How to do multi tenancy with QLDB? Like, I have multiple apps writing to audit and would like to have a virtual separation for each app in the same cluster.

There are a few potential ways to go about this, that ultimately may depend on your use-case(s). Within a single ledger you could leverage attributes in each document to differentiate between tenants. You could leverage multiple ledgers in QLDB in a single account with the [default quota](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/qldb/latest/developerguide/limits.html#limits.default). It may also be the case that you want even more separation and may consider creating multiple accounts and leveraging something like [AWS Control Tower](https://aws.amazon.com/controltower/).

All that said, the best approach could depend very heavily on your use-case(s), as well as other AWS products that you’re using. You may want to reach out to AWS support on this as well to potentially connect with the relevant Solutions Architect who could consult on approaches, given your specific use-case(s).

Comment: Maybe interesting for everyone reading here about data Redaction capabilities of QLDB: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/qldb/latest/developerguide/working.redaction.html